# Remove unknown Device in LVM

Tags: centos, lvm

Does anyone know how to remove below unknown device(0) from lv/vg/pv?

CentOS 6.7

```
[root@localhost ~]# lvs -a -o +devices
  Couldn't find device with uuid kAWxh3-gucl-ZrAl-GOYw-uLKV-xrBB-J9EJf5.
  Couldn't find device for segment belonging to VolGroup/lv_home while checking used and assumed devices.
  LV      VG       Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert Devices
  lv_home VolGroup -wi-ao--p- 164.61g                                                     /dev/sda2(12800)
  lv_home VolGroup -wi-ao--p- 164.61g                                                     unknown device(0)
  lv_root VolGroup -wi-ao----  50.00g                                                     /dev/sda2(0)
  lv_swap VolGroup -wi-ao----   4.90g                                                     /dev/sda2(29340)


pvdisplay
  Couldn't find device with uuid kAWxh3-gucl-ZrAl-GOYw-uLKV-xrBB-J9EJf5.
  Couldn't find device for segment belonging to VolGroup/lv_home while checking used and assumed devices.
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda2
  VG Name               VolGroup
  PV Size               119.51 GiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              30594
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          30594
  PV UUID               6O0VwG-V12w-QkXG-8vNu-Kjns-zQvs-UU0NXK

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               unknown device
  VG Name               VolGroup
  PV Size               100.00 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              25599
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          25599
  PV UUID               kAWxh3-gucl-ZrAl-GOYw-uLKV-xrBB-J9EJf5

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdc1
  VG Name               VolGroup
  PV Size               200.00 GiB / not usable 1.34 MiB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              51199
  Free PE               51199
  Allocated PE          0
  PV UUID               nxQOZp-KY1t-UfkE-wWmO-Aq1V-ZEOx-VxocqO

 vgs -a -o +devices
  Couldn't find device with uuid kAWxh3-gucl-ZrAl-GOYw-uLKV-xrBB-J9EJf5.
  Couldn't find device for segment belonging to VolGroup/lv_home while checking used and assumed devices.
  VG       #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree   Devices
  VolGroup   3   3   0 wz-pn- 419.50g 200.00g /dev/sda2(0)
  VolGroup   3   3   0 wz-pn- 419.50g 200.00g /dev/sda2(12800)
  VolGroup   3   3   0 wz-pn- 419.50g 200.00g unknown device(0)
  VolGroup   3   3   0 wz-pn- 419.50g 200.00g /dev/sda2(29340)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `pvremove` or its better to use `vgreduce` , with UUID or if it doesnt work then use `vgreduce --all` to clean up things and add again what you want to be in VG.

Comment: vgreduce with -f option wont work, because this unknown device is already in LVS  list.  system asked me to do the cleanup from lv level first.

Comment: Plus, I cannot do --all because, this VG is control all filesystems

Answer (score 1):

`vgreduce --removemissing VG` works fine.